# File existence promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-system, promise

I hate to have to write a custom exists promise every time I need to know if a file exists, so I came up with this. Thoughts?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"))

function fsExists(_path){
  return fs.lstatAsync(_path)
  .then(function(){ return true })
  .catch(function(){ return false })
}

module.exports = fsExists
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the `catch` and `then` parts are unnecessary. A `then` accepts a resolve and reject handler, which you can treat a boolean.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"))

module.exports = fs.lstatAsync
```

Usage would simply be

```
var stat = require('yourFsStatModule');

stat('path/to/file').then(function(){
  // it exists
}, function(){
  // it doesn't exist
});
```